# Error in stored procedure near 0

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the follow stored procedure in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @SQL_DtsAcumGPSDataZeros NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SQL_DtsAcumGPSDataZeros= N'SELECT [counter]
      ,[iID]
      ,[iVehicleID]
      ,[fTripDistance]
      ,[dtDateTime]
      ,[fLongitude]
      ,[fLatitude]
      ,[bLatLongValid]
      ,[fSpeed]
      ,[bIgnition]
      ,[bStopFlag]
      ,[fTripTime]
      ,[bWorkHours]
      ,[iLogReason]
      ,[bLatLongValidGuess]
      ,[bAux1]
      ,[bAux2]
      ,[bAux3]
      ,[bAux4]
      ,[bAux5]
      ,[bAux6]
      ,[bAux7]
      ,[bAux8]
  INTO ' + @DtsAcumGPSDataZeros + N' 
  FROM ' + @DtsAcumGPSData +
  N' WHERE fTripDistance= 0'
  EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL_DtsAcumGPSDataZeros
  PRINT @SQL_DtsAcumGPSDataZeros
  GO
```

And get the error

> *Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>
>   Incorrect syntax near '0'.*

Comment: Can you explain the structure of fTripDistance table? What are `@DtsAcumGPSDataZeros` and `@DtsAcumGPSData` ?

Comment: the DtsAcumGPSData contain the field fTripDistance, this field is dsts type float an not allow null. the variable atDtsAcumGPSDataZeros only is set as follow: DECLARE atDtsAcumGPSDataZeros VARCHAR (50);
SET atDtsAcumGPSDataZeros='To'+ atNAutobus + 'DtsAcumGPSDataZeros' where atNAutobus is of data type NVARCHAR(4) --at=arroba

Comment: What does your `PRINT` command show?? Call it *before* executing the SQL statement!

Comment: print command only print the sqlstatement and puting the value of the variables and the stament that was executed

Comment: the print command : SELECT [counter]
      ,[iID]
      ,[iVehicleID]
      ,[fTripDistance]
      ,[dtDateTime]
      ,[fLongitude]
      ,[fLatitude]
      ,[bLatLongValid]
      ,[fSpeed]
      ,[bIgnition]
      ,[bStopFlag]
      ,[fTripTime]
      ,[bWorkHours]
      ,[iLogReason]
      ,[bLatLongValidGuess]
      ,[bAux1]
      ,[bAux2]
      ,[bAux3]
      ,[bAux4]
      ,[bAux5]
      ,[bAux6]
      ,[bAux7]
      ,[bAux8]
  INTO To245DtsAcumGPSDataZeros 
  FROM To245DtsAcumGPSData WHERE fTripDistance= 0

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 0 as parametr

```
DECLARE @SQL_DtsAcumGPSDataZeros NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @id int = 0
SET @SQL_DtsAcumGPSDataZeros= N'SELECT [counter]
      ,[iID]
      ,[iVehicleID]
      ,[fTripDistance]
      ,[dtDateTime]
      ,[fLongitude]
      ,[fLatitude]
      ,[bLatLongValid]
      ,[fSpeed]
      ,[bIgnition]
      ,[bStopFlag]
      ,[fTripTime]
      ,[bWorkHours]
      ,[iLogReason]
      ,[bLatLongValidGuess]
      ,[bAux1]
      ,[bAux2]
      ,[bAux3]
      ,[bAux4]
      ,[bAux5]
      ,[bAux6]
      ,[bAux7]
      ,[bAux8]
  INTO ' + @DtsAcumGPSDataZeros + N'
  FROM ' + @DtsAcumGPSData +
  N' WHERE id = @id'
  EXEC sp_executesql @SQL_DtsAcumGPSDataZeros, N'@id nvarchar(100)', @id
  PRINT @SQL_DtsAcumGPSDataZeros
```